# Visual Studio 2015 bower dependencies missing dist/js folder?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, bower

note sure if this is a bug in Visual Studio 2015 but I thought I'd ask the community to see if anyone else has experienced this odd behaviour.

Steps to reproduce;

1. Create a new AspNet5 Empty Website.
2. Add bower config file
3. Alter the .bowerrc directory to "bower_components"
4. Add bootstrap ~3.3.6 as a dependency to the bower.json file
5. right click the bower.json and select "Restore Packages"

Take a look in the bower_components/bootstrap/dist folder and you will see that there is no js folder.

Now, open up Package Manager Console and type "bower install bootstrap"

This creates another bower_components folder in the root of the solution folder with the same folder structure as the one in the web app with one exception, the INCLUSION of the javascript files??

Has anyone else seen this, am I missing something fundamental about bower?

Comment: Did you found a solution for it, having the same problem right here...